# How to dynamically update shipping progress bar with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, progress-bar, shopify

I have made a shipping progress bar on my product page which updates when someone adds to cart, or updates/removes the quantities from the cart drawer.

The green progress bar that progresses as the customer adds items to their cart won't update dynamically like the price and the success message does e.g.

[image]

Here is the liquid code:

```
{% if section.settings.is_free_shipping_bar %}
        {% assign promote_txt = section.settings.promote_free_shipping_txt | escape %}
        {% assign unlocked_txt = section.settings.unlocked_free_shipping_txt | escape %}
        {% assign threshold = section.settings.free_shipping_threshold | times: 100 %}
        {% assign shipping_quotient = settings.free_shipping_threshold %}
        {% assign shipping_procent = cart.total_price | divided_by: shipping_quotient | at_most: 100 %}
        {% assign value_left = threshold | minus: cart.total_price %}
        {% assign value_left_money = value_left | money %}
  <style>
    .shipping-bar {
      background-color: {{ section.settings.color_bg }};
      position:relative !important;
    }
    
    .shipping-bar-success {
      background-color: {{ section.settings.success_color_bg }};
    }

    .shipping-bar--link:hover {
      {% assign brightness = section.settings.color_bg | color_brightness %}

      {% if brightness <= 192 %}
        {% assign lightenAmount = 255 | minus: brightness | divided_by: 255 | times: 16 %}
        background-color: {{ section.settings.color_bg | color_lighten: lightenAmount }};
      {% else %}
        {% assign darkenAmount = 255 | divided_by: brightness | times: 8 %}
        background-color: {{ section.settings.color_bg | color_darken: darkenAmount }};
      {% endif %}
    }

    .shipping-bar__message {
      color: {{ section.settings.color_text }};
      padding: 10px 0;
      font-size: max(calc(var(--typeBaseSize) - 6px), 11px);
      letter-spacing: 0.2em;line-height: 1.42;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight:bold;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative !important;
    }
    
    .free-shipping__progress {
      position:absolute !important;
      background-color: #25a799;
      left: 0!important;
      top: 0!important;
      height: 100% !important;
      width: {{ shipping_procent }}%;
    }
    
    #shipping__progress {
      position:absolute !important;
      background-color: #25a799;
      left: 0!important;
      top: 0!important;
      height: 100% !important;
      width: {{ shipping_procent }}%;
    }
    
  </style>
    
         <div class="shipping-bar" data-promote="{{promote_txt}}" data-unlocked="{{unlocked_txt}}" data-threshold="{{threshold}}" data-quotient="{{shipping_quotient}}" data-procent="{{shipping_procent}}">
            {% if value_left <= 0 %}
            <p class="shipping-bar-success shipping-bar__message">{{unlocked_txt}}</p>
           {% else %}
            <div id="shipping__progress"></div>
           <p class="shipping-bar__message">{{promote_txt | replace:'[value]' , value_left_money}}</p>
           {% endif %}
        </div>
        

    {% else %}
    </div>
      {% endif %}
```

Here is my JS:

```
document.addEventListener('page:loaded', function() {
    
theme.ShippingBar = (function() {
  
  var bar = document.querySelector('.shipping-bar');
 
  if(bar)
  {
  var promote_txt = bar.dataset.promote;
  var unlocked_txt = bar.dataset.unlocked;
  var threshold = bar.dataset.threshold;
  }
  
  function update()
  {
    if(bar)
    {
    $.getJSON('/cart.js').then(
    
      function(cart) {
        
        var value_left = threshold - cart.total_price;
        var value_left_money = theme.Currency.formatMoney(value_left,theme.moneyFormat);
        const shipping__progress = document.getElementById('shipping__progress');
        let shipping_quotient = threshold / 100;
        const shipping_procent = Math.min(cart.total_price / shipping_quotient, 100);
        shipping__progress.style.width = '${shipping_procent}%';
        
        if(value_left <= 0){
            bar.innerHTML =  '<p class="shipping-bar-success shipping-bar__message">' + unlocked_txt + '</p>';
        }
        else{
            bar.innerHTML = '<div id="shipping__progress"></div><p class="shipping-bar__message">' + promote_txt.replace('[value]',value_left_money) + '</p>';
        }
      }
      
    );      
    }
  }
  return { update:update }
}) ();

  });
```

I use `theme.ShippingBar.update()` wherever there is a `updateCart` or `addCart` to update the bar.

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to update the JS code, this JS code is not working.

Comment: @Onkar Do you know where I've went wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you able to share the URL to the website?

Comment: @Onkar Yeah sure, it's https://www.babyesmee.co.uk

Comment: it seems your JS code is okay and just issues with placement of code and it need debug over the website, so I think without testing the code over the website, any suggestions are waste of time.

Comment: @Onkar Where's the best place to start? I'm new to JS.

Comment: I think you need to take bits of help or try the same code `theme.js`, not into the `theme.liquid`

Comment: In the expression `'${shipping_procent}%'`, should you not be using backticks, ie `\`${shipping_procent}%\``.

Comment: You have the full power of jQuery available to you but you aren't using it.

Comment: @Onkar I've fixed it myself, thanks for the input though.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 It works fine without the backticks for me.

Comment: @ChrisBeattie, I must have misread the code. Good luck.

Comment: @ChrisBeattie Glad to know you able to fix the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it myself, here's my working code:

```
    {% if section.settings.is_free_shipping_bar %}
            {% assign promote_txt = section.settings.promote_free_shipping_txt | escape %}
            {% assign unlocked_txt = section.settings.unlocked_free_shipping_txt | escape %}
            {% assign threshold = section.settings.free_shipping_threshold | times: 100 %}
            {% assign shipping_quotient = settings.free_shipping_threshold %}
            {% assign shipping_procent = cart.total_price | divided_by: shipping_quotient | at_most: 100 %}
            {% assign value_left = threshold | minus: cart.total_price %}
            {% assign value_left_money = value_left | money %}
        
             <div class="shipping-bar sticky-shipping" data-promote="{{promote_txt}}" data-unlocked="{{unlocked_txt}}" data-threshold="{{threshold}}" data-procent="{{shipping_procent}}">
                {% if value_left <= 0 %}
                <p class="shipping-bar-success shipping-bar__message">{{unlocked_txt}}<img style="float:right;margin-top: -4px;" height="25px" width="25px" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0352/4044/4035/files/delivery-van_976a90b1-6b6d-41a5-af16-65828cba1c6a.svg?v=1612052428"/></p>
               {% else %}
                <div id="free-shipping__progress"></div><p class="shipping-bar__message">{{promote_txt | replace:'[value]' , value_left_money}}<img style="float:right;margin-top: -4px;" height="25px" width="25px" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0352/4044/4035/files/delivery-van_976a90b1-6b6d-41a5-af16-65828cba1c6a.svg?v=1612052428"/></p>
               {% endif %}
            </div>
```

JS

```
    
theme.ShippingBar = (function() {
  
  var bar = document.querySelector('.shipping-bar, #free-shipping__progress');
 
  if(bar)
  {
  var promote_txt = bar.dataset.promote;
  var unlocked_txt = bar.dataset.unlocked;
  var threshold = bar.dataset.threshold;
  var shipping_procent = bar.dataset.procent;
  }
  
  function update()
  {
    if(bar)
    {
    $.getJSON('/cart.js').then(
    
      function(cart) {
        
        var value_left = threshold - cart.total_price;
        var value_left_money = theme.Currency.formatMoney(value_left,theme.moneyFormat);
        var quotient = threshold * 100;
        var procent = Math.min(cart.total_price / quotient) * threshold;
        
        if(value_left <= 0){
            bar.innerHTML =  '<p class="shipping-bar-success shipping-bar__message">' + unlocked_txt + '</p>';
        }
        else{
            bar.innerHTML = '<div id="free-shipping__progress"></div><p class="shipping-bar__message">' + promote_txt.replace('[value]',value_left_money) + '</p>',
            document.getElementById("free-shipping__progress").style.width = procent + '%';
        }
      }
    );      
    }
  }
  return { update:update }
}) ();

  });
```

CSS

```
.shipping-bar {
          background-color: {{ section.settings.color_bg }};
          position:relative !important;
          margin-top: 5px;
          border-radius: 10px;
        }
        
        .shipping-bar-success {
          background-color: {{ section.settings.success_color_bg }};
          border-radius: 10px;
        }
 
        .shipping-bar--link:hover {
          {% assign brightness = section.settings.color_bg | color_brightness %}
 
          {% if brightness <= 192 %}
            {% assign lightenAmount = 255 | minus: brightness | divided_by: 255 | times: 16 %}
            background-color: {{ section.settings.color_bg | color_lighten: lightenAmount }};
          {% else %}
            {% assign darkenAmount = 255 | divided_by: brightness | times: 8 %}
            background-color: {{ section.settings.color_bg | color_darken: darkenAmount }};
          {% endif %}
        }
 
        .shipping-bar__message {
          color: {{ section.settings.color_text }};
          padding: 13px 20px;
          font-size: max(calc(var(--typeBaseSize) - 6px), 11px);
          letter-spacing: 0.16em;
          line-height: 1.42;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font-weight:bold;
          text-align: left;
          position: relative !important;
        }
        
        #free-shipping__progress {
          position:absolute !important;
          background-color: #25a799;
          left: 0!important;
          top: 0!important;
          height: 100% !important;
          border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
          width: {{shipping_procent}}%;
        }
```